# Deleting values from array with np.diff

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to edit an array. The array has two columns. One for X-Values, the other for Y-Values. The X-Values are 0.0025 steps (0, 0.0025, 0.005, etc.) but sometimes there are wrong steps and I need to delete those. The others recommend that I use the following:

```
data = data[~np.r_[True, (np.diff(data[:,0])>0)&(np.diff(data[:, 0])<0.0024)]]
```

The problem is that the first value always gets deleted and the second problem is that it doesn´t just delete the wrong step but the one after it too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first element is always being deleted is because you invert the output of `np.r_` which prepends `True` to the output of `np.diff`. When using `~`, that gets turned into a `False`, and thus the first element gets deleted.

My guess that the step after gets deleted too is because np.diff checks the difference between consecutive elements. Consider:

```
0.0025, 0.005, 0.008,  0.01, 0.0125
               ~~~~~
# The diff here is going to look like:
       0.0025, 0.003, 0.002, 0.0025
```

Note how the wrong element results in a wrong diff both before AND after that element.

If that is unexpected behavior, then you should not use `np.diff`, instead compare with the expected steps directly using `np.arange`

```
import numpy as np

# Solution:
data[ np.isclose(data[:, 0], np.arange(start, stop, 0.0025)) ]

# with I'm guessing start=0, and stop=data.shape[0]*0.0025
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn´t seem to delete the wrong values. Do I need to add something like, `if data[ np.isclose(data[:, 0], np.arange(start, stop, 0.0025)) ] == true` then delete these values?